# How do I get the right value with multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, aggregate

I am running into an issue when I try to return the correct value with two conditions and then a third if a certain situation arises.

The column in question is `U`, the `Determining Entity`. I have this formula in cell `U2` dragged down,

`=INDEX(N:N,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($N$2:$N$10)/((AGGREGATE(14,6,$R$2:$R$10/
((AGGREGATE(14,6,$P$2:$P$10/($S$2:$S$10=S2),1)=$P$2:$P$10)*($S$2:$S$10=S2)),1)=$R$2:$R$10)*(AGGREGATE(14,6,$P$2:$P$10/
($S$2:$S$10=S2),1)=$P$2:$P$10)),1))`

What I want is to show the largest amount held by a entity that falls under a given `Parent`.  If there are two limits that are the same under the same `Parent`, then the `Editing IRR` is to decide whom should be of bigger concern for us (the higher the number, the bigger the concern).  I would like it look like this,

**EDIT x2**

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0"><tr><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">N</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">P</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;text-align:center;vertical-align:top">Q</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">R</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">S</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">T</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">U</th></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Limit</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Rating</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Edited IRR</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Parent</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Largest Limit</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Determining Entity</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25 </td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-4</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">20</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">75</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Ben's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Ben's Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">75</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">75</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Ben's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Siobhan's Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0.5</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Irish Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0.5</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Siobhan's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Food</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods </td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Sushi</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Veggies</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-5</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Sushi</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Sushi</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-4</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">20</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Sushi</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Cola Palace</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Sushi</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Jamba Juice</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">20</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Sushi</td></tr></table>
```

but this is what I am getting,

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0"><tr><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">N</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">P</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;text-align:center;vertical-align:top">Q</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">R</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">S</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">T</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">U</th></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Limit</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Rating</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Edited IRR</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Parent</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Largest Limit</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Determining Entity</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25 </td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-4</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">20</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">75</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Ben's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Ben's Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">75</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">75</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Ben's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Siobhan's Store</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0.5</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Irish Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0.5</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Siobhan's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Food</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods </td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Veggies</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-5</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob'sStore</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Sushi</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-4</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">20</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Cola Palace</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">0</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Store</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Jamba Juice</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">20</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">I-3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Good Foods</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">25</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;vertical-align:top">Bob's Store</td></tr></table>
```

The formula is almost perfect but if the `Limit` and `Edited IRR` exactly match another entity's `Limit` and `Edited IRR` that is higher in order on the list, then the former results as the Determining Entity even though the two are unrelated.

I originally had an unanswered question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928485/max-num-based-off-second-value), but I hope with more and clearer information it will be able to be solved as it still seems to be the best most elegant solution.

Please help because I missed an imaginary deadline.

Comment: I thought I was making progress until I noticed that the value in R13 is different between the two data samples.

Comment: Perhaps a copy-and-pasteable table would be of benefit here. I for one am not prepared to manually recreate your dataset from the picture you provided in order to test potential solutions.

Comment: @Jeeped, you are right, I thought I corrected that because I caught that but pasted the wrong .jpg twice.  Edit coming.  The Limit and Edited IRR should be the same.

Comment: Ok, you are right @XOR LX, I will prepare that instead

Comment: Edited, hope that is better

Comment: 25|20 in line 6 and 25|20 in line 13 are the same numbers. How do you know that Good Foods has a parent ID of 59213? That should be the determining factor.

Comment: @Jeeped that was indeed another error.  Anywhere the Parent was the same, the Parent ID should have been the same.  I made adjustments to to the tables and pics to match.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood correctly, but, in `U6`:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(R$6:R$15/10^6+(S$6:S$15=S6)*P$6:P$15)),N$6:N$15)`

Regards

Comment: you somehow understood me.  This is what I was looking for.  Will now look into FREQUENCY and how this actually works.  Sorry it took so long to respond but I was on my way home and wanted to make sure I made all of the adjustments to the existing tables and pictures.  I tried post better tables but it proved more difficult than expected with the number of columns.  Lesson learned.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You're welcome. Your tables were an excellent help, so thanks. Explanation of this construction here, if you're interested: https://excelxor.com/2015/02/22/return-entry-corresponding-to-maximum-value-based-on-conditions/

Comment: XOR, I am sorry that I have to take away the answer but, I still can not seem figure out the original snag.  Your LOOKUP formula and the original AGGREGATE formula seem to have the same issue.

Comment: I've made a small amendment to the formula (and also replied to your comments at my site). Can you let me know if that improves matters?